# How to stop leaving the current page in Ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

According to Ionic 3 documentation, this is supposed to work:

```
ionViewWillLeave(): boolean {
    if (this.cantLeave) {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'You can\'t leave',
            subTitle: 'You stay and work.',
            buttons: ['Oh sorry']
        });
        alert.present();
    }
    return this.cantLeave;
}
```

Yet it doesn't. The alert appears, but the page changes nonetheless. However here it says that `return true` or `return false` will tell Ionic to carry on with the page change or stop it.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use **Nav Guards**. 
Check the Nav Guards section [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

The lifecycle hook is **`ionViewCanLeave()`** not `ionViewWillLeave`

```
ionViewCanLeave(): boolean {
    if (this.cantLeave) {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'You can\'t leave',
            subTitle: 'You stay and work.',
            buttons: ['Oh sorry']
        });
        alert.present();
    }
    return this.cantLeave;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't do anything, it doesn't even get triggered. Maybe because I am using a tab set to navigate?

Comment: thats weird.. are you able to print `cantLeave` value?

Comment: Yes, and it's a proper boolean. It's actually a bit more complicated in my code, it gets its value from a service, so I didn't include it in the example. But it works fine, that's not the issue.

Comment: _its value from a service_.. in that case there isnt enough info here... maybe its because its async? you will have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: No, it's not async. It's a simple singleton service which stores values throughout the app. It's a simple boolean value. But even if I replace it with a single variable, like in the example, it doesn't work.